# Traefik, docker swarm and portainer. Serving robots.txt file

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm, robots.txt, traefik

I'm playing around with my homelab and I'm trying to include robots.txt file.
I'm launching traefik and portainer using this docker_compose file. This is using Docker swarm mode

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: "traefik:latest"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --providers.docker.network=web
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.email=SOME_EMAIL@gmail.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.storage=./acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.file.filename=/dynamic.yaml
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik-data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./traefik-data/dynamic.yaml:/dynamic.yaml
    networks:
      - web
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`monitor.SOME_DOMAIN.dev`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.entrypoint == true
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

      - ./portainer-data:/data
    networks:
      - web
    deploy:
      labels:
        # Portainer
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.SOME_DOMAIN.dev`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.service=portainer"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.entrypoint == true
networks:
  web:
    external: true
volumes:
  portainer-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ./portainer-data
```

and then I'm trying to launch nginx to serve robots.txt file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  antybots:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: antybots
    volumes:
      - /mnt/config/robots/robots.txt:/usr/share/nginx/html/robots.txt:ro
    deploy:
      labels:
        # Antybots
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.antybots.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.*}`) && Path(`/robots.txt`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.antybots.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.services.antybots.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.http.routers.antybots.service=antybots"
        - traefik.http.routers.antybots.priority=99
    networks:
      - web
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

But all I got when I enter to https://SOME_DOMAIN.dev/robots.txt or https://ANYTHING.SOME_DOMAIN.dev/robots.txt I receive either 404 or empty content of robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

which I not I placed in my robots.txt file.

I verified that container properly sees my robots.txt file.
I think that might be caused by redirection to https which is probably caused by

```
 - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
 - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
```

Is there any way to bypass this for this one file and serve it as http? Or it might be caused by something else?

Comment: Read traefik logs, they will tell you where the requests are routed.

Comment: @AlexD 
I checked treafik logs, and found this json:
https://pastebin.com/Jc5HBDta
And it looks ok. I also checked if other container can see curl this file using this ip and it worked

Comment: You need to look for traefik access logs. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/observability/access-logs/

Comment: @AlexD ok I added access-logs and now I can see 
10.0.0.2 - - [15/Feb/2024:20:19:01 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "-" "-" 159 "SERVICE_NAME@docker" "http://10.0.1.110:80" 2ms
this line
Which means that traefik is using rules set by these line:
 - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.SOME_DOMAIN.dev`)"
but is ignoring 
- "traefik.http.routers.antybots.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.*}`) && Path(`/robots.txt`)"
I thought that setting priority
   - traefik.http.routers.antybots.priority=99
should help, but it is not.